# Gradle '' project refresh failed

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've just installed fresh version of current android studio. And gradle sync outputs this error:

```
"Error:Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected"
```

Anyone know what's wrong? I've tried different versions of gradle (1.1 and 2.1).

Comment: Have You solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the problem with having incompatible versions of `asm` dependency. Try `gradle dependencies` to verify which dependency is causing the conflict. Then, one of conflicting jars must be eliminated from classpath.

Unfortunately there's no simple solution to this problem because it's unpredictable which version of library will be read and hen used first.

As far as I remember there is a conflict between version 3 and 4 `asm` libraries that are downloaded as a dependency.